# Beamer (Boadilla theme): Color of itemize subitems inside blocks

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

When using the "Boadilla" theme in the beamer package, I noticed that the bullets of subitems in the `itemize` environment have different colors inside `block` environments than outside. The problem is that the color is almost the same as the background, so the individual bullets are barely visible.

Is there a way to change the subitem bullet color to the same color used outside of `block`s?

Here is an example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{block}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subitem 1
                \item subitem 2
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item subsubitem
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item subitem 1
            \item subitem 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subsubitem
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Compiled MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand very well how does it work, but a *fast* solution is to add these lines to the preamble or inside a group where you wish to get that result.

```
\colorlet{custom}{beamerstructure}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{custom}$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{custom}$\bigstar$}}
```

I tried to patch the *Boadilla theme* definitions.

### Full Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\colorlet{custom}{beamerstructure}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{custom}$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{custom}$\bigstar$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{block}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subitem 1
                \item subitem 2
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item subsubitem
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item subitem 1
            \item subitem 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subsubitem
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]